# ExtJS - Rest store post changes in one call

Tags: http, rest, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJS 4.2 REST store.

I want to sync the store with the server after adding some records to it.

each record is being transferred in a different post request.

I would like to make one call to the server with a list of new records.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting [`batchActions`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-cfg-batchActions) to `true`... But there may be a reason why they have explicitly disabled it for REST proxy. Maybe it's because it's not RESTFul in its spirit, or maybe it's because it doesn't work...

Comment: It wouldn't be RESTFul if different kind of CRUD operations were batched in the same request, because the HTTP method wouldn't match the semantic for all the operations. Also, I don't know what REST purists would think about batching DELETE requests (as opposed to sending one request on each resource URL).

Comment: I get you, but I am batching POST requests of one type of resource. So I think I am still OK... ;)